# convert shell script into tcl script

Tags: linux, shell, tcl

My TCL script

```
set a "Linux raj.centos7.com 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 22 16:42:41 
UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
set b "raj.centos7.com"
puts $a
puts $b
if { [string match $a  *$b*] }
  {
   puts "Match";
    }else   {
    puts "No Match";
    }
  fi
```

I am getting the following error while ran the script

```
wrong # args: no script following " [string match $a  *$b*] " argument
    while executing
"if { [string match $a  *$b*] } "
    (file "./ak.tcl" line 8)
```

Comment: set a "Linux raj.centos7.com 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 22 16:42:41 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux" set b "raj.centos7.com" puts $a puts $b if { [string match $a $b] } { puts "Match"; }else { puts "No Match"; } fi

Comment: Please edit your question instead of putting code in comments.

Answer (score 1):

**Your script is *syntactically* incorrect!**

You *must* be careful with newline characters and spaces. In particular, you must start the body of your `if` on the same line as the test expression, and you must separate `else` from the script fragments around it.

This:

```
if { [string match $a  *$b*] }
  {
   puts "Match";
    }else   {
    puts "No Match";
    }
```

should become this:

```
if { [string match $a  *$b*] } {
    puts "Match";
} else {
    puts "No Match";
}
```

*ALL* I have changed there has been whitespace.

Also, there probably isn't a `fi` command so you'll get another error in a few lines. (The `fi` is a shell-ism…)

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, but it's not working  #!/usr/bin/tclsh
set a "Linux raj.centos7.com 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 22 16:42:41 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
set b "^raj.centos7.com\S*"
set host [exec uname -n]
puts $a
puts $b
set unameinfo [exec uname -a]
if { [string match $a  *$b*] } {
    puts "Match"
} else {
     puts "No Match"
}   
~[root@ts~]# ./sta.tcl
Linux raj.centos7.com 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 22 16:42:41 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
^raj.centos7.comS*
No Match

Comment: @Manikandan : Code posted in this way is practicaly unreadable. Also, in your original posting, you asked about a specific problem, which has been solved by the answer given by Donal Fellows. If you experience a new problem, create a new post.

Comment: @DonaldFellows : Just a small note to your (correct) answer: The `else` is optional; and the braces around `[string match $a  *$b*]`, while they don't hurt, are not necessary in this case either.